# I cannot create a Cloud Project after installing Azure SDK 2.0

Tags: azure

I installed the new Azure SDK from the Web Platform Installer.

Now when I try File > New Project > Cloud > Windows Azure Cloud Service > OK

Then I get this error message:

```
Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService.Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0 ...
```

I have tried everything I can think of including uninstall of the 1.8 SDK, uninstall of the 2.0 SDK and reninstall.  Always I get this message. I cannot see anything about this on the internet. My install gave no error messages.

Also noticed that now in Server Explorer I only have Data Connections, Servers, Windows Azure Service Bus and WIndows Azure Web Sites. There's nothing for storage.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be wrong.

Comment: The more I read the more I become convinced that I should never move to SDK 2.0

Comment: Worked fine on a new install. Hope someone can come up with a solution. I just tried a 45 minute "repair". Looked like it re-installed everything but still no luck. Have you been reading about other problems with SDK 2.0 ?

Comment: Yeap, and a lot of them.

Comment: I've the same issue and I also can't open any old Azure project (created with 1.8). Visual Studio just show this warning: "This project is associated with Windows Azure Tools - v2.0 which is not installed. You must download the tools and reload the project.". I've also tried to uninstall 1.8 SDK and reinstalled 2.0 SDK -> still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with skd 2.0
Even trying repairing or installing missing features won't work.
After hours spent on repairing and reinstalling, the only solution I found was to uninstall BOTH Visual Studio and Azure sdk, and installing them again.

After the reinstallation it works fine, but I still have no clue why :P

Answer (score 0):

I keep a development VM for each SDK that comes out. When I upgrade older projects to newer SDKs there are bugs, sometimes bugs without workarounds. I've learned the hard way that installing a new SDK is dangerous.

If you can, develop inside a VM and take occasional snapshots. Otherwise, you do end up reinstalling Visual Studio and installing the original SDK that you first created you project with. -Richard

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue on multiple machines after upgrading to 2.7, 2.8, and/or 2.9. Reinstalling VS, VS Updates, and/or SDKs would sometimes help, but sometimes not. The last time no combination of installs worked.

I finally ran Visual Studio with logging enabled via [Devenv /log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx), and according to the `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version#}\ActivityLog.xml` file, there was an error merging the configuration file located at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version#}\devenv.exe.config` I deleted that config file and restarted Visual Studio and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Visual Studio using [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) did the trick for me.

Then I did a clean install of Visual Studio and Azure SDK, and everything worked just fine!